# How do you cope with tons of web fonts when copying and pasting from web pages?

Tags: mail.app, font, notes.app, copy-paste, text-editor

Whenever I copy something from the web and paste it in my Mail or Evernote, or Apple Notes, it always brings the text style from the page and inserts those weird looking fonts in my mail, or notes.

My solution for that is to paste it in a plain text editor, VIM in my case, and then copy and paste where I need it to get rid of the style. It's pretty elaborate process, especially when I need to copy/paste often during research.

I'm wondering how other people cope with the fonts, and what's a better solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most people I know set the paste shortcut to invoke paste and match style. Here is the command to change:

[image: before changing the shortcut]

You can paste with style when you really want it, but for me 95% of the time I don’t want the style and only the raw text.

1. Open System Preferences
2. Select Keyboard
3. Go to the Shortcuts tab
4. Select App Shortcuts
5. Select the + button
6. Type **Paste and Match Style** into the Menu Title field
7. Select the Keyboard Shortcut field
8. Enter **⌘V** as the shortcut.

You can then have another shortcut for the “normal” paste that includes styled text when desired. (Or just click paste on the rare occasions you want that.)

Comment: Or just get used to clicking **⌥⌘V** (or whatever your default shortcut is – on my system it's ⌥⇧⌘V) on those occasions where you need to get rid of formatting. That allows you to keep consistency with other apps. Generally when pasting, ⌘V will maintain as much formatting as is feasible, while either ⇧⌘V or ⌥⇧⌘V will be used for pasting without formatting (depending on the program – from memory, Word uses the latter by default, while InDesign uses the former, and going by your screenshot and my system, Mail uses either depending on [something?]).