# Make Notes app copy text as plain text

Tags: mac, notes.app

Is there a way to have the Notes app on Mac copy text as plain text? I use Notes a lot but it copies text as rich text. This can causes problems when pasting text to certain apps that pick up on the unwanted font properties of Notes.

Comment: Do those certain apps have a "Paste and Match Style" option on the Edit menu? That's what I usually use to get around unwanted formatting. https://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/set-paste-match-style-default-mac-osx/

Comment: This seems like all about pasting so a duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/357367/how-do-you-cope-with-tons-of-web-fonts-when-copying-and-pasting-from-web-pages/357368#357368

Comment: Or dupe of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84823/how-to-force-os-x-notes-application-to-lose-formatting-when-i-paste-text-from-cl If pasting into notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the app where you're pasting the text you've copied from Notes, make sure your document format is plain text, and then use the "Paste and Match Style" command in the Edit menu (or hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>opt</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>):

[image]

Any macOS app that uses a system standard text field should support this.

Answer (score 1):

If you copy a lot i can highly recommend a Clipboard extension App like '[Clipy](https://github.com/Clipy/Clipy)' (Open Source), which offers the ability to copy/paste text as plain text with a special keyboard shortcut (which you can define as you like).

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy your data into TextEdit (default app on all macs)
2. Convert 'rich text' to 'Plain text'.
3. Copy your data
4. In Google sheets, select 'Edit'/'Paste special'/Values only'

Comment: Why do you need steps 1-3 in that case?