# How to completely turn off auto-format and copying format in Apple Numbers

Tags: numbers

I want to completely disable auto-format and copying format on Copy/Paste.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Does ***paste and match style*** work for you? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/357367/how-do-you-cope-with-tons-of-web-fonts-when-copying-and-pasting-from-web-pages

Comment: I eventually stop using Numbers, it doesn't work the way I would like to use it